# Why does an error occur in one case, but not in the other, and how to fix it?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, special-functions, numerical-value

Why do errors appear for this Kx[11, 15] when this Kx[11, 14] is considered without error? How to fix it?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Psi[r_, 
   n_] := (2 E^(-(r/n)) Sqrt[n!/(-1 + n)!] Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n, 
      2, (2 r)/n])/n^2;

Kk[r_, n1_, n2_] := 
 FullSimplify[
  Psi[r, n2]*Laplacian[Psi[r, n1], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]]

Kx[n1_, n2_] := -1/2*
  NIntegrate[Kk[r, n1, n2]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}]

In[68]:= Kx[11, 14]

Out[68]= 0.00200019

In[69]:= Kx[11, 15]

During evaluation of In[69]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in r near {r} = {205.38}. NIntegrate obtained -0.0033904 and 3.93073776641158`*^-9 for the integral and error estimates.

Out[69]= 0.0016952
```

Comment: You may increase the maximum number of recursions: `MaxRecursion -> 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the integral analytically and then set values. We will check the `[11,14]` values that do not cause any issues

```
Psi[r_, n_] := (2 E^(-(r/n)) Sqrt[n!/(-1 + n)!] Hypergeometric1F1[
      1 - n, 2, (2 r)/n])/n^2;
Kk[r_, n1_, n2_] := 
 FullSimplify[
  Psi[r, n2]*Laplacian[Psi[r, n1], {r, θ, φ}, "Spherical"]]
numKx[n1_, n2_] := -1/2*
  NIntegrate[Kk[r, n1, n2]*r^2, {r, 0, ∞}]
Kx[n1_, n2_] := -1/2*Integrate[Kk[r, n1, n2]*r^2, {r, 0, ∞}]
```

And now we check

```
Kx[11, 14] - numKx[11, 14] // Chop
```

> [image: Blockquote]

If you want to be pedantic about it you can see how much off the results are

```
Kx[11, 14] - numKx[11, 14]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

And now you can calculate

```
Kx[11, 15]
```

> [image: Blockquote]